# shutdownd service missing on Ubuntu server 16 LTS

Tags: server, shutdown

Following Rinzwind's kind advice as to how to detect a pending scheduled shutdown, I hit the following problem (on a fairly fresh Ubuntu 64bit 16.04.1 server install):

```
root@m________a:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
root@m________a:~# shutdown +5
Shutdown scheduled for Sun 2016-10-16 20:18:40 BST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
root@m________a:~# systemctl status systemd-shutdownd.service
● systemd-shutdownd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@m________a:~#
```

Yes, I have `systemd-suspend.service`, and also `-halt`, `-poweroff`, and `-reboot` services.  Where is the shutdown service?  Shutdown still works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled
```

This was added to systemd 220 release as explained here: 
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Systemd-Kill-Shutdownd